# Insert into Table using multiple columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, insert

Assume that we have a table that looks like this:

[image]

`Comma1` Column is a personID value, and `comma2`, `comma3`, `comma4` etc (this table is created dynamically so it can be more than 4 columns) are teamIDs.

Now, I have another table called `personTeam` that keeps relations between `personids` and `teamids`. For example if person 13 is a member of team 3 and team 8 then in `personTeam` table should be 2 records (13,3 and 13,8).

What i need is, using this table in the attached picture, to insert `personids` and `teams` to the `PersonTeam` table. For example for person 149 I want an insert (149,10) but for person 221 i want (221,7) ,(221,8), (221,11).

Is there any way to work around this?
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to pull this off is using `UNION` or `UNION ALL`

For example:

```
insert into personTeam (personid, teamid)
select comma1 as personid, comma2 as teamid
from commastable
where comma2 is not null
union
select comma1, comma3
from commastable
where comma3 is not null
union
select comma1, comma4
from commastable
where comma4 is not null;
```

A `UNION` will only return unique records, but to do that it has to sort the result.  Which can make it slightly slower than a `UNION ALL` which would just stick the results of the unioned queries together.
I expect that the source data wouldn't contain duplicates, so the `UNION` is just used to make sure it only inserts unique tupples.

And if you want to make this repeatable?
Just put that query in a sub-query and left join it to personTeam .

```
insert into personTeam (personid, teamid)
select q.personid, q.teamid
from
(
  -- add the query with the unions here
) as q
left join personTeam as t 
  on (t.personid = q.personid and t.teamid = q.teamid)
where t.personid is null;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for **UNPIVOT** clause in **SELECT** statement.

*TEST DATA*

```
declare @t1 as table (
    comma1 int,
    comma2 int,
    comma3 int,
    comma4 int 
)

insert into @t1 values
     (149,10,null,null)
    ,(221, 7,8,11)
    ,(278,3,10,null);

select * from @t1;
```

*SOLUTION EXAMPLE*

```
select comma1 as personid , value1
into #TmpTeam
from @t1 unpivot ( value1 for Team in ( comma2,comma3,comma4)) as p;

select * from #TmpTeam;
```

You can use other syntax to insert results of the query into your table. This is just an example.

Comment: Hi there , unpivot sounds good indeed, but as i mentioned above this table is created dynamically so it may have 5 columns instead of 4. In this case i need unpivot that is also dynamic . COrrect?

Answer (score 0):

If I was doing this as a one off, I would simply do three inserts.

```
INSERT INTO personTeam (personids, teamids)
SELECT comma1, comma2 from table
```

```
SELECT comma1, comma3 from table WHERE comma2 is null
```

```
INSERT INTO personTeam (personids, teamids)
SELECT comma1, comma4 from table WHERE comma2 is null and comma3 is null
```

The unpivot command is used to normalise data to tables. It only works from 2005+

```
select comma1, teamids
from input
unpivot
(
  teamids
  for teams in (comma2, comma3, comma4)
) as u;
```

Answer (score 0):

For it to work with any number of columns, you can build a dynamic query and execute it.

```
DECLARE @dynSql VARCHAR(max)
DECLARE @table_name VARCHAR(max) = 'tbl'

SELECT @dynSql = (
  SELECT 
     'INSERT INTO personTeam SELECT comma1, ' + 
      COLUMN_NAME + 
     ' FROM ' + 
     @table_name + 
     ' WHERE ' + 
     COLUMN_NAME + 
     ' IS NOT NULL; '
  FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
  WHERE TABLE_NAME = @table_name
  AND ORDINAL_POSITION != 1
  FOR XML PATH('')
)

EXECUTE(@dynSql);

SELECT * FROM personTeam
```

Just set the @table_name variable to the name of your input table.

What this does is build a string like this

```
INSERT INTO personTeam SELECT comma1, comma2 FROM tbl WHERE comma2 IS NOT NULL;
```

for each column (except the first; i.e. comma2, comma3, ...) in your input table and then executes that statement.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/53fcd/24